# PHP Regex String Parse

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I have a string made up with the following structure - An ID in parentheses followed by the value for that ID, the string could contain and number of ID and value pairs. e.g.
(00)CONTENT1(R3)CONTENT2(27)CONTENT3(5C)CONTENT4

I would like to parse the string and return an array with the ID in the parentheses at the element key and the content as the value e.g.

```
Array
(
    "00" => "CONTENT1"
    "R3" => "CONTENT2"
    "27" => "CONTENT3"
    "5C" => "CONTENT4"
)
```

Any assistance with a regex to parse this string would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Well, the regex for that would be something like `\(\w+\)(\w+)`

Comment: I am using an online regex tester to try and return the desired output but as of yet none of the expressions seem to work as desired.

Comment: What is the expression you tried, and what is the gap between the result and your aim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested this on https://regex101.com/ and it splits your string like you expect:

```
$string = '(00)CONTENT1(R3)CONTENT2(27)CONTENT3(5C)CONTENT4';
preg_match_all('/\((\w+)\)(\w+)/mi', $string, $matches);

// Just reformatting to the desired output
$result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);

print_r($result);
```

Which gives:

```
Array
(
    [00] => CONTENT1
    [R3] => CONTENT2
    [27] => CONTENT3
    [5C] => CONTENT4
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or without regex, using `str_replace` and `parse_str`:

```
<?php
$str = str_replace(['(', ')'], ['&', '='], '(00)CONTENT1(R3)CONTENT2(27)CONTENT3(5C)CONTENT4');

parse_str($str, $array);

print_r($array);
```

https://3v4l.org/Mkl2Z

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [00] => CONTENT1
    [R3] => CONTENT2
    [27] => CONTENT3
    [5C] => CONTENT4
)
```